# How to use a random string for the window title bar?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want my program's title bar be a random string from an array. I am using FreeGLUT to initialize the window (the "glutCreateWindow()" function), but I am unsure how to make it work.

Here's what I have:

```
std::string TitleArray[] = 
{
"Window title 1",
"Window title 2",
"Window title 3",
"Window title 4",
"Window title 5"
};
std::string wts = TitleArray[rand() % 6];

const char* WINDOW_TITLE = wts.c_str();
```

and here's the "glutCreateWindow()" call:

```
glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);
```

Whenever I debug the title bar is blank, though. The "glutCreateWindow()" function requires a const char*, too, so I couldn't just place the 'wts' variable inside the parameters.

Comment: Might want to change your array access to `rand() % 5` because  you have indexes 0-4. Don't know if that will solve your situation, however.

Comment: That displayed the second one in the array, thanks. :) Any idea on how I could get a different one to display each time?

Comment: @Charles: Did you seed the random number generator `std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` ?

Comment: No. I am not entirely sure where to put the little bit of code for the seed. All the code I've posted except for the "glutCreateWindow()" is not in a method. It's just global. And I can only put srand in a method.

Comment: @Charles: Just add it right in WinMain or main (whichever you are using) at the beginning.

Comment: Oh wow that was easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, for future reference, random number generators are not actually random. They use a specific algorithm to generate the numbers. Whenever you do not seed the generator, it will give you the same number each time. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is, other than %6 instead of %5.  Here is an example console program showing use of rand():

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

std::string TitleArray[] = 
{
"Window title 1",
"Window title 2",
"Window title 3",
"Window title 4",
"Window title 5"
};

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    srand ( time(NULL) ); // seed with current time
    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
    {
        std::string wts = TitleArray[rand() % 5];
        cout << wts.c_str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


Console output:

Window title 3
Window title 4
Window title 5
Window title 2
Window title 4
Window title 4
Window title 1
Window title 3
Window title 2
Window title 1
Window title 2
Window title 1
Window title 2
Window title 5
Window title 4
Window title 5
Window title 3
Window title 1
Window title 4
Window title 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If you leave out the srand() or always use the same seed, you will get the same output for each run.